# Looking for a Betting UML Diagram advice

Tags: database, database-design, uml, relational-database, database-schema

I'm trying to develop a betting system, this is a part of my UML diagram of the database model.

```
MATCH(match_id, home_team, away_team, time)
FIRST_HALF(match_id, home_team_goals, away_team_goals)
SECOND_HALF(match_id, home_team_goals, away_team_goals)
BETTYPE(bet_type_id, match_id, odd, bet_name)
```

I have some doubts regardins my MATCH -> BETTYPE relationship. Is this a good practice, or it's better to have all bet types for a match in the MATCH table, for example:

```
MATCH(match_id, home_team, away_team, winner, first_half_winner, second_half_winner, home_team_goals, away_team_goals...)
```

Which is the better solution? first or second?
Who can describe me a good UML diagram for this mini application? I want a schema which will make my job easier regardins the db queries.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't put the odds in the bet type table. Every bet has different odds, even if they are of the same bet type.
About where to put the score, You have 2 valid options:

1. keeping the half time, full time, overtime and penalty score directly in the match table.

Pros:

- A simple flat table is fast and simple to read from

Cons:

- Keeping multiple nullable columns when it's easy to avoid them

sample table:

```
TblMatch
--------
Match_Id (pk)
Match_Date
Match_Time
Match_HomeTeam (fk to team)
Match_AwayTeam (fk to team)
Match_FirstHalfHomeTeam
Match_FirstHalfAwayTeam
Match_SecondHalfAwayTeam
....
```

2. Keep a table for score:

Pros:

- Normalized
- Flexible
- Scalable

Cons:

- Selects are a bit more complicated since you need to join 3 tables.

sample tables:

```
TblMatch
--------
Match_Id (pk)
Match_Date
Match_Time
Match_HomeTeam (fk to teams)
Match_AwayTeam (fk to teams)

TblScoreType
------------
ScoreType_Id (pk)
ScoreType_Name (unique)

TblMatchScore
-------------
MatchScore_Id (fk to match)
MatchScore_ScoreType (fk to score type)
MatchScore_Team (fk to team)
```

I would probably go for the second option.

As for bets, have a bet type table and an actual bets table:

```
TblBetType
----------
BetType_Id (pk)
BetType_Name (unique)
-- other relevant columns

TblMatchBet
------
MatchBet_Id (pk)
Bet_BetType (fk to bet type)
Bet_Match (fk to match)
Bet_Odds

TblBet
------
Bet_Id (pk)
Bet_MatchBet_Id (fk to match bet)
Bet_Amount
Bet_User (fk to users)
-- other relevant columns such as date and time and stuff like that)
```